# Несколько IP на одном сервере

Tags: ip, сервер

У меня скорее теоретический вопрос:

Может быть у одного сервера много IP адресов? и как это может быть реализовано? много сетевых карт?

И еще, например фирма провайдер (или хостинг фирма) она ведь может выдавать клиентам выделенные IP, но как это устроено? Может ли кто-нибудь, объяснить примерную схему как это работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Множество IP адресов на одном интерфейсе, в Debian Linux например, обеспечивается алиасами в /etc/network/interfaces . Вот тут есть кратенько, и с конкретным примером: [http://how-it.ru/public/root/191-debian**ubuntu***kak_ukazat_neskolko_ip_adresov_dlya_setevoi_karty__interfeisa*.html](http://how-it.ru/public/root/191-debian__ubuntu___kak_ukazat_neskolko_ip_adresov_dlya_setevoi_karty__interfeisa_.html)

Что же касается внешних выделенных IP, то, как правильно писал тут Арчер, проще всего это сделать мостом на реально существующий внешний интерфейс провайдера с уже имеющимся фиксированным адресом. Некоторые провы также пользуются VPN с выходом на внешний IP, но лично мне этот геморрой не нравится.

Comment: во, то что надо! спасибо :) я так понимаю, хостинг-сервера как раз и назначают алиасы клиентам?

Comment: Внутренние адреса - да! А насчёт внешних я там добавил. Пардон, меня можно неверно понять. Я имел в виду множество садресов самого сервера. Адреса внутренней локальной сети распределяются исходя из адреса сети и её маски. Можно по DHCP, мможно и руками. Но главное - чтобы соотношение адрес локальной сети/маска выполнялось!

Comment: ясно, спасибо :)

Answer (score 3):

наверное нужно начать с [Сетевой модели OSI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI) (внимательнее смотреть на 3 уровень)

далее: [IP-адрес](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81), [Маршрутизатор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), [Коммутатор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), [Сетевой мост](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82)

а потом, если уж появятся вопросы - они должны стать конкретными.

Добавлю ещё [VLAN](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlan), [Сетевой интерфейс](http://xgu.ru/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81), [Создание виртуального интерфейса](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/30275/)

Comment: я знаю что такое ip-адрес или роутер и про модель OSI в курсе, но это не отвечает на мой вопрос... это всё слишком общие понятия. вы бы еще дали мне ссылки на определения ОС или что такое жесткий диск(это как ни крути тоже часть сервера) не лучше ли объяснить на вашем уровне? а те вещи которые я не пойму, я могу и загуглить

Comment: если кидать ссылки на общие понятия из википедии, то я могу на этом сайте, на все вопросы так отвечать, но понравится ли это тем, кто их задает?

Comment: Мой рейтинг на этом сайте говорит, что нравится. Давайте конкретный простой вопрос, который является центром непонимания. Только один. Потом, только по очереди, второй.Если по вашим вопросам:Может быть у одного сервера много IP адресов? -даи как это может быть реализовано? - с помощью сетевого моста, напримермного сетевых карт? - не обязательно, всё можно сделать на однойостальные вопросы слишком размыты для меня, сложно на них просто ответить, если вы не понимаете принципов бридживания реальных и виртуальных сетевых интерфейсов. А если понимаете, то непонятно, что нужно объяснять..

Comment: ну первый конкретный вопрос, есть прямо в посте "Может быть у одного сервера много IP адресов?" вроде конкретно? а более конкретно я не могу задать, т.к. я не знаю, как устроены хостинг-сервера со своими IP.п.с. во конкретный вопрос, как получить список всех IP сервера? это конечно не совсем по вопросу темы, это скорее практический вопрос, но тоже интересно.

Comment: "т.к. я не знаю, как устроены хостинг-сервера со своими IP" не является камнем преткновения, у них устроено также, как у всех.как получить список всех IP сервера? - ifconfig в Unix-like системе и ipconfig в windows, или в справке по работе с той системой, в которой это хотите узнать.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо. палец вверх рейтинг не позволяет поставить.

Comment: ничего страшного ))

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример работы виртуальных интерфейсов [Создание нескольких IP адресов на одном сетевом интерфейсе Linux](http://plutonit.ru/view_post.php?id=538)

Answer (score 1):

```
ifconfig ethX add x.x.x.x netmask x.x.x.x
```

Вот и все)